# Newbie question regarding Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I just started learning Selenium, and would like to try a simple example.

However, I get the following exception when I run the code:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/WebWindowListener
```

Does anyone know how to mitigate this?

Thank you.

Comment: can you expand this to show the code that caused this error?

Comment: I have just solved this issue.  It seems I need to include selenium-server-standalone-2.0a5.jar as well.

Answer (score 1):

NewbieIntern solved this issue himself, but, I'll put in this answer so people on Google are happy.

You have to include the selenium server jar or, in NewbieIntern's words, "selenium-server-standalone-2.0a5.jar". This version number will probably change.